# Add my .net-core app to startup or boot

Tags: startup

I'm new to Linux and I'm testing a .net-core app on Ubuntu 18.04. It works fine but I also want to add it to the startup.
I found some walkthroughs and the closest I got was adding my app to services on startup but it was disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used gnome-session-properties, and added a script which should be executable to startup.
the script is simply:

```
gnome-terminal -- ~/[PATH TO EXECUTABLE]
```